# Error in Firefox when making SQLite calls via Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, sqlite

I have a site that is fully functioning in Chrome/Safari and heavily relied on SQLite to store/access data. However, when testing in Firefox, it errors on the first call, openDatabase(). This is my fairly standard openDB function:

```
function openDB(){
try {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('not supported');
    } else {
        var shortName = 'tales';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'Tall Tales Database';
        var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
        db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize); 
        // You should have a database instance in db.
    }
} catch(e) {
    // Error handling code goes here.
    if (e == 2) {
        // Version number mismatch.
        alert("Invalid database version.");
    } else {
        alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
    }
    return;
}
```

}

Like I said - openDatabase is undefined when I alert it, and the Unknown error that prints is "unsupported". I assume SQLite is actually supported in Firefox, am I doing something wrong or does it require browser-specific code?

Thank you!
Claudia

Answer (score 3):

Firefox doesn't have that feature. Mozilla doesn't think SQLite is appropriate for the web, so in Firefox 4 they will be instead opting for and implementing the IndexedDB spec. draft by the W3C (incl. proposals by Mozilla). Here's a nice blog post detailing the differences: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/comparing-indexeddb-and-webdatabase/

So yes, you will have to use client specific code in order to support FF4 - at least until IndexedDB is implemented in the other major browsers. For anything before FF4, there is no support for any client database (not counting localStorage, etc.).

Comment: It's not "their own database API" though.  It is also a W3C standard, and IndexedDB is being actively worked on and implemented by Mozilla, Chromium, and Microsoft.

Comment: @sdwilsh: Well what I meant is that Mozilla made large contributions to the asynchronous API specifically. It's their own API in the sense that they thought it up and designed it. I edited my post anyways as to make it clearer that it is not a "closed" solution -- that is, that they are actively trying to the specification to its final state for use by all. Thank you for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if (typeof(window.openDatabase)=='undefined') {
  alert(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function openDB(){
try {
    if (!!window.openDatabase) {
        var shortName = 'tales';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'Tall Tales Database';
        var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
        db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize); 
        // You should have a database instance in db.
    } else {
        alert('not supported');
    }
} catch(e) {
    // Error handling code goes here.
    if (e == 2) {
        // Version number mismatch.
        alert("Invalid database version.");
    } else {
        alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
    }
    return;
}
```

That should work.